# Android virtual device is not running

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I started learning Android development, i installed Android Studio.
When trying to launch the app, the Virtual device window open but i get the following errors:

> Failed to create Context 0x3005 could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize
>   OpenglES emulation, using software renderer. could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB emulator: device fd:588 HAX is not working
>   and emulator runs in emulation mode emulator: The memory needed by
>   this VM exceeds the driver limit.

Any solutions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem .Try this way .

Open `AVD Manager -> Select the device -> click Edit and uncheck the Enabled checkbox.` And setting the RAM to `512 Mb or 768 Mb` & Heap size `64`. After that Restart Your Tool .I hope it will works

Comment: Better way use 3rd party emulators which enhanced features like genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Many people have faced this issue due to different reasons. A few solutions could be:

1. Increase emulator RAM
2. Use GPU HOST check box

Comment: Same problem :(
_emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 2048MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1536MB.
emulator: device fd:696
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit._

Comment: set Ram to 512 and heap size 64. I have these settings and actually in HAX driver settings i made ram to 384 and still it works like a charm in Eclipse IDE, will try to find better and working solution for u.

Try to delete existing and make a new one.
First start without GPU host then terminate it then OPen settings then check GPU host and give it a try.

This happens to me with Blank black screen..

Comment: I tried everything, nothing worked that's why i didn't give any voting :(

Comment: Ok, tomorrow i will try to find some good solution for u, kindly update ur question if any new error came , in case.

Comment: Try this, go to folder where android sdk is installed and find folder there by name of "Intel" there you will have HAXM set up, re run it if u have installed previously then set memory to 512MB that is good enough. 

Coudn't find?
Open eclipse and go to  SDK Manager and download Intel x86 HAXM. then Install it and set Ram size :) Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Calips buddy any update.? Did u try my latest given suggestion.?

Answer (score 0):

Set the RAM to 768MB and heap size to 64.
Try with host GPU and without it, it depends on your system.

It takes 2 or 3 minutes for emulator to boot usually.

Answer (score -1):

Just increase emulator RAM and go.

Comment: emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 2048MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1536MB.